# Inputting a cell address in a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

so I'm in Sheet1 of a workbook and i'm trying to set up a formula where the end result is 'Sheet2'!$B:$B.
I'm doing this so that i can use that result as an input for an Index Match formula. Any ideas?
I've tried playing with the Address function.

Comment: please show some test data and expected output.  skipping the need for creating a string and then using INDIRECT will be quicker.  It may be needed, but there may be a better way.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! If you already know the formula, why are you not using it?

Comment: Please share some sample data,, or  the WB on cloud,, along with the INDEX Match array formula. If you want to use B2 (where u have end result) as MATCH then it can be used directly, another is INDIRECT,,,!